# Help! I do not know what to do!

Tags: rigging, blender-internal-render-engine

I need to get out of animating mode, and I can't! This must be simple. I just do not know what to do.

Comment: `shift + ctrl` perhaps? More information

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please use a descriptive title that describe the issue? Avoid words like "help" and "question", since that basically describes all posts here.

Comment: Could you please put in a lot more info like a video or picture